# SSD that heats not too much

Tags: ssd

Could anybody recommend desktop's SSD that works with lower temperature (I mean that would not heat too much) ?

Or may be at least brand which bother about it... It seems nobody is interesting in that but I do not like idea to put  two SSD, that can heat till 80 degree (by Celsius) under the load into my MicroATX overcrowded case.

May be some mobile models would fit better for me?

Other recommendations? E.g. too prefer lower size?

My corsair's SSD worst temp was 80 degree. I would like to minimize those numbers.
[image: SMART Status (worst temp of my corsair)]

May be SSD drives for the same bus (SATA III) but with lower form factor (M2 ? "half-size SATA" ?) should be preferable for cases where temperatures problems can be observed?

Comment: What is your budget for the devices and what is the ideal temperature range? Is there a size requirement (in GB)? Is there anything else that we need to know about these SSDs?

Comment: No special requrements for price or size. But it would be interesting too learn how temperature depends from size. I would prefer 100 GB to 200 GB  if they would be "cooler".

Comment: Given your current stated requirements, the 4GB CompactFlash card with CF-to-IDE adapter I'm currently using as a budget SSD in one of my systems would meet your requirements -- and it certainly runs cool.  Are you *sure* you don't have any requirements for interface, capacity, or speed?

Comment: Friends, relax, please. Do not make it too  complex. Just normal 2.5 inch SSD drives for normal desktop computer. 50-100-200 Gb. I

Answer (score 3):

Solid State Drives use about 8W of power while HDD use 12W or so on average. That doesn't directly show heat output, but it should help you get an idea. SSD aren't any hotter than HDD besides NVME SSD's. For example, NVME 950 Pro from Samsung is known to get up to 100C and start thermal throttling to prevent damage. If you don't know what NVME is, then I will just tell you that as long as you are using a red SATA cable to connected the drive to the motherboard you are fine.

Comment: Thank you for your considerations. How you would explain this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3hhdWwvh5kI ?